# Service worker show same notification 2 times

Tags: push-notification, angular5, service-worker

I have implemented web psuh notification using FCM. Its working fine at backend. At frontend angular5, I have used service worker to fetch that push notifications. At that function its enter only one time but sometime shows 2 notifications one with icon and other without it.

```
function showNotification(title, options) {
  var notificationOptions = {
    'tag': options.tag,
    'badge': 'assets/icons/icon-128x128.png',
    'icon': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/images/logos/logo-icon.png',
    'vibrate': [300, 100, 200, 400, 500],
    'data': options.data,
    'body': options.body,
    'sound': 'default'
  };
  if(options.data.type === 'media') {
    notificationOptions.image = options.data.media;
  } else {
    notificationOptions.body = options.body;
  }
  return self.registration.showNotification(title, notificationOptions);
}
```

I have searched for this bit not get any solution.

Advance thanks. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the code where you call the `showNotification()` function?

Comment: I had already showed that function in the question. Please check